# hiveserver2 can not run sql on Spark on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

Here is my versions:
Hive: 1.2
Hadoop: CDH5.3
Spark: 1.4.1

I succeeded with hive on spark with hive client, but after I started hiveserver2 and tried a sql using beeline, it failed.

The error is:

```
2015-11-29 21:49:42,786 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - 15/11/29 21:49:42 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/cdh/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar at http://10.96.30.51:10318/jars/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar with timestamp 1448804982784
2015-11-29 21:49:43,336 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - 15/11/29 21:49:43 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm297
2015-11-29 21:49:43,356 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - 15/11/29 21:49:43 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getClusterMetrics of class ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl over rm297 after 1 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over immediately.
2015-11-29 21:49:43,357 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - 15/11/29 21:49:43 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm280
2015-11-29 21:49:43,359 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - 15/11/29 21:49:43 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getClusterMetrics of class ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl over rm280 after 2 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 477ms.
2015-11-29 21:49:43,359 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - java.net.ConnectException: Call From hd-master-001/10.96.30.51 to hd-master-001:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
2015-11-29 21:49:43,359 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) -    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

My yarn's status is that hd-master-002 is active resourcemanager and hd-master-001 is backup. 8032 port on hd-master-001 is not open. So of course, connection error occurs when trying to connect to hd-master-001's 8032 port.

But why she tried to connect a backup resourcemanager.
If I use hive client command shell on spark on yarn, everything is ok.

PS: I didn't rebuild the spark assembly jar without hive, I only removed 'org.apache.hive' and 'org.apache.hadoop.hive' from built assembly jar. But I do not think it is the problem because I succeeded with hive client on spark on yarn.

Comment: I found that the error occurs where the sql is 'select count(*)'. If the sql is 'select * ', it will be ok even if using hiveserver2

Comment: We found if we use "beeline -n root", it is ok